# Advantages of jQuery UI over richfaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, richfaces

I know jQuery and richfaces are two different libraries and are used in defferent scenarios.

But I faced few issues in last project when I was integrating latest `jQuery(1.6)` with `richfaces(3.3.0)` libraries, there were lot of conflicts between jQuery versions in richfaces and the ones I was loading manually.

So for the new module in same project I was just thinking about developing complete UI with jQuery and use JSON as data exchange format. Also use richfaces script functionality to communicate between UI and backing-beans.

I am also aware that advantages of using java models in UI cannot be leveraged if I use jQuery and JSON.

Apart from that could you forsee any factors that I need to consider before jumping into the implementation?

Some of needed functionalities are

```
1. Drag and drop
2. Adding dynamic form fields like multiple ph numbers, address fields
3. Pre fill the form using data from DB
4. Submit the form with dynamically added form fields
5. Panels, Accordion views
```

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to choose between the two unless there is a reason you can not use RichFaces 4.
I've been using RichFaces 4 + jQuery UI combination. RichFaces 4 includes jQuery 1.5.x. There were no conflicts at all. At places I've used RichFaces components, and at places I've used jQuery UI components.As you said `<a4j:jsFunction>` enables them to communicate with each other and at times I've also used `Servlets` cause they offer greater flexibility.